# How can i dispose all dynamic controls correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, and when `Form1` loads it shows `Form2`:

```
Form frm = new Form2();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm.Show();
}
```

---

`Form1` has a button to dynamically create 10 buttons on `Form2`.

```
private void btnCreateButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int t=0;t<10;t++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Button " + t.ToString();
        button.Location = new Point(10, (10+(button.Height*t)));
        frm.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Here are the two forms after clicking [Create Buttons] one time.

[image: create dynamic buttons]

---

Then the goal is that when the [Dispose] button is clicked on `Form1`, it will properly remove and dispose all of the buttons on `Form2` that were created in the first step. But I have a problem about destroying the dynamic objects created.

```
private void btnDisposeAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control control in frm.Controls)
    {
        if (control != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(control);
            control.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to destroy this dynamic buttons, dispose method not work correctly. Only some of dynamic buttons in `Form2` disappear.

[image: destroy buttons]

what's wrong in my code?
thanks

Comment: i try to remove all dynamic objects by this code and all done well:`code` while (frm.Controls.Count > 0) frm.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: That works too, and for the same reason! When you're always disposing the control at `Controls[0]` you aren't iterating the collection and changing it at the same time. It's another good approach and will also address the root cause of the behavior.

Comment: @IV.thanks bro :) your details is very useful :) thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior from your code. I believe the problem comes from iterating the `ControlCollection` at the same time you're changing that collection. To avoid this issue, cast it into an array which will insulate you from the changes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form frm = new Form2();
    public Form1() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        buttonCreateButtons.Click += CreateButtons_Click;
        buttonDisposeButtons.Click += DisposeButtons_Click;
        frm.Show(this);
        frm.Location = new Point(Right + 10, Top);
    }
    private void CreateButtons_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
        {
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = $"Button {t}",
                AutoSize = true,
                Margin = new Padding(0,10,0,0),
            };
            button.Location = new Point(10, button.Margin.Top + ((button.Margin.Vertical + button.Height) * t));
            frm.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
    private void DisposeButtons_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var control in frm.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray())
        {
            control?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Thx to @Jimi for the reminder that `Remove()` is implicit in the call to `Dispose()`. And at the same time I'm incorporating that improvement, I'm going to specifically target just controls of type `Button`, leaving other controls on `Form2` intact.

Comment: thanks for your atention @IV. :) i try to dispose all dynamic object by this : while (frm.Controls.Count > 0) frm.Controls[0].Dispose(); and all works fine, but i surprised about this behavior ,everytime i pressed destroy some object disposed :)))

Comment: The convention in c# is to name methods with Pascal-casing, not camel-casing, and methods that are named `On*` are for raising the event, not handling it.

Comment: @Enigmativity thx, editing the answer to use Pascal-casing does make it read more clearly. Now I'm trying to understand the second part of your comment. If I call `this.OnCreateControl()` in `Form1` what event will I be raising?

Comment: I mention this as an example of an `On*` method that has no event to raise. From the [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#remarks)  docs: "The `OnCreateControl `method [...] allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. _This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class._"

Comment: @IV. - The `On*` methods are `protected virtual void` and in the parent method there will be an `Invoke` call for the event being raised - hence that the `On*` methods raise the event. In a child class, instead of attaching to the event you can simply `override` the method and call `base.On*` to ensure you still raise the event, but you are able to then add your own code to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain your own `List` of Buttons in Form1, and directly dispose of them from there...

```
Form frm = new Form2();
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); // <-- List of Buttons

private void btnCreateButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Button " + t.ToString();
        button.Location = new Point(10, (10 + (button.Height * t)));
        frm.Controls.Add(button);
        buttons.Add(button); // <-- add it to your OWN list!
    }            
}

private void btnDisposeAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // walk list backwards...
    for(int i=buttons.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        buttons[i].Dispose();
    }
    buttons.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,i will try this solution too :)